# INSERT SELECT, Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' without overwriting other table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert-into

This is my first question so please be kind if this question is already been asked.
And my english is not very well ;)
I have a XAMPP MySQL-server and want to make a `INSERT SELECT` statement, but if I run the statement i get this error: `#1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'` 
Here is my SQL-statement: `INSERT INTO amt (Bezeichnung)
SELECT Bezeichnung
FROM fach`

But I don't want to overwrite the table "amt", it should only be append at the table fach.

I want to add this table [picture of table "fach"](http://imageshack.com/a/img841/2254/u3dc.jpg)
to this. [picture of table "amt"](http://imageshack.com/a/img834/7331/qxp1k.jpg)

"Bezeichnung" = GER, description;
"amt" = GER, function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set your ID column to be auto increment:

```
ALTER TABLE `amt` MODIFY COLUMN `id_amt` INT auto_increment
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO amt (id_amt, Bezeichnung)
SELECT (select coalesce(max(id_amt), 0) + 1 from amt), Bezeichnung
FROM fach
```

Comment: No sorry, this statement deosn't work.
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'X' for key 'PRIMARY'
X = 15+numbersOfTrys